# set behaves unexpectedly in a python class

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I have some objects like rectangles on a canvas, and for each one I want to have a set, which contains the id's of its neighboring cells

here's the code for the class, `idC` are the ids i'm interested in, they are assigned by Tkinter's create_rectangle function to each cell

```
class Cell(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, canvas, row, column):
        # make a 10x10 rectangle in the given row, column
        x0 = column * 10
        y0 = row * 10
        x1 = x0 + 10
        y1 = y0 + 10         

        super(Cell, self).__init__(canvas, (x0, y0, x1, y1), "white")

        self.get_neighbours()


    state = 'dead'
    neighbours = set()
    border = set()

    def get_neighbours(self):

        if self.idC % 95 == 1: self.border.add('left')  #the numbers are like so because my canvas is 950x950
        if self.idC % 95 == 0: self.border.add('right')
        if self.idC < 96: self.border.add('top')
        if self.idC > 8930: self.border.add('bottom')
        if 'left' not in self.border: self.neighbours.add(self.idC - 1)
        if 'right' not in self.border:self.neighbours.add(self.idC + 1)
        if 'top' not in self.border:
            if 'left' not in self.border:self.neighbours.add(self.idC - 94)
            self.neighbours.add(self.idC - 95)
            if 'right' not in self.border:self.neighbours.add(self.idC - 96)
        if 'bottom' not in self.border:
            if 'left' not in self.border:self.neighbours.add(self.idC + 94)
            self.neighbours.add(self.idC + 95)
            if 'right' not in self.border:self.neighbours.add(self.idC + 96)

    def change_state(self):
        self.state = 'alive' if self.state == 'dead' else 'dead'
        color = "black" if self.state == "alive" else "white"
        print(self.idC)
        print("neighbours:")
        #print(self.neighbours)
        print(len(self.neighbours))
        if not GameOfLife.running: self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.idC, fill=color)
```

and here is how I create all the cells in another class with my other widgets:

```
    for i in range(95):
        for p in range(95):
            self.organism.append(Cell(c, i, p))

    for cell in self.organism:            
        c.tag_bind(cell.idC, '<ButtonPress-1>', lambda _, x = cell: x.change_state())
```

what happens is that all the ids get added to the set `neighbours`, except for the one which triggers the function; also everything else works fine - clicking on a cell prints its id correctly

it must be some newbie mistake but I have no idea what's going wrong..

update: i found out that every cell also gets marked as being on all borders on the canvas so it must be that as the function gets called again and again it adds all the ids to the same set, instead of making a different set for every instance of the class. I tried calling it from different places, but I still get the same results...

Comment: The problem is your closure, in that last snippet: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Comment: @DanielRoseman but I thought I already fixed that  with the `x = cell` part... I had this problem when `change_state()` was triggered for the last cell no matter where I clicked, and now it doesn't do it anymore; now all the different ids get added to the set and it gets a length of 95^2 - 1

Comment: Ah, you're right, sorry; I misread the code.

Comment: sorry, what is `c` in the last code block?

Comment: @dbliss `c` is what i called my canvas, maybe i should have made it clearer indeed

Comment: have you checked that `border` is not empty after `if self.idC > 8930: self.border.add('bottom')` is called?  and what is `idC`'s exact value on a sample run of this code that causes the undesired result?

Comment: @DanielRoseman how would a problem all the way down there, even if there were one, influence what gets into `neighbours`?  does `c.tag_bind` potentially remove items from `neighbors`?  `neighbors` is created with `Cell(c, i, p)`, in the preceding `for` loop.  (but i don't know anything about `tkinter`.)

Comment: @dbliss, i solved the problem by moving `get_neighbours()`, and the associated variables into `cell`'s parent class, which is just a couple of lines that make an object class out of `tkinter`'s `create_rectangle(...)` function

still no idea why it behaved this way in the child class

Comment: keep in mind that in the code in your question, you're calling the parent class's `__init__` before the child's.  it might be worth it to track the code line-by-line on initialization, keeping an eye on the value of all variables at each step.  though painstaking, there's no question that would reveal the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I moved the whole `get_neighbours()` and all the variables associated with it to the parent class, and now it works fine

I still have no idea why it behaves that way